# Code working locally but not on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have the following code, which is going to form part of an Alexa Skill, it works fine locally using node.exe but when I put it into Lambda the fetch returns nothing! and speechOutput just has "Your headlines are:".  Can anyone suggest why it does not work?

```
    var speechOutput="Your headlines are:";
     var urlPrefix = 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http://news.com/feed/';
    const https = require('https');
    //console.log(https.get(urlPrefix));
    https.get(urlPrefix, (res) => {
       var body = '';
       res.on('data', function(data)
       {
          body += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function()
        {
          var result = JSON.parse(body);
          jItems=result.items;
          for ( var i=0 ; i < jItems.length ; i++ ) {
                     var article = jItems[i];

                         speechOutput +=", "+article.title ;
                                  }
          //console.log(speechOutput);
        });

    }).on('error', function(e)
       {
        console.log('Error: ' + e);
      });
```

Comment: Have you included any referenced libraries in the deployment package you uploaded to lambda?

Comment: Tom, no shouldn't need to should I as I am only using https? The code runs without errors, would I not expect to see errors if libraries are missing?

Comment: Pretty sure this is to do with Asyncrhronous running but I am not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: Are there any errors from this function in CloudWatch?

Comment: maybe you are sending the response back to the echo, before the request is finished... did you watched the logs?http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html

Answer (score 4):

I'd add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation. :\

Looking at the code, the lambda is probably shutting down before your callbacks complete. Which is why you do receive the first logging, but not the rest. And yes, you should get an error if the require('https') failed, so that's probably not the case.

Can you post the rest of your code? Where do you invoke context.done in our lambda or, in newer versions of node, do you do the callback to the handler?